# XState action is not called for `machine.transition()`

Tags: javascript, xstate

I have a simple machine:

```
import { createMachine } from 'xstate'

export const machine = createMachine(
  {
    predictableActionArguments: true,
    schema: {
      context: {} as { elapsed: number },
      events: {} as { type: 'AT_SAFE_ZONE' } | { type: 'WALKING' },
    },
    initial: 'a',
    states: {
      a: {
        on: {
          WALKING: {
            target: 'b',
          },
        },
      },
      b: {
        on: {
          AT_SAFE_ZONE: {
            target: 'a',
          },
        },
        exit: ['calculateWalk'],
      },
    },
  },
  {
    actions: {
      calculateWalk: async (context, event) => {
        console.log('>>> calculateWalk', context, event)
      },
    },
  }
)
```

And when I use it:

```
const { initialState } = machine

const nextState = machine.transition(initialState, { type: 'WALKING' })

console.log(nextState.value)

const nextState2 = machine.transition(nextState, { type: 'AT_SAFE_ZONE' })
```

I can see the states changing from `a` to `b` then to `a` again, but the action is never called.

Context: I'm testing the machine on vitest, I can see all logs except from the function `calculateWalk`. I tried many things: with and without array of actions, inside and outside of the "on" block... Nothing worked.

Comment: That's interesting, if you assign the elapsed context in your calculateWalk it seems to work as expected. Looks like a limitation of the transition method, because if the machine is interpreted, it logs everything https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/elated-kirch-hsw9v7?file=%2Findex.js%3A38%2C35. Probably it is worth it to ask on the stately discord server.

Comment: Using a interpret (const service = interpret(machine)) worked fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transition function of a FSM can be understood as a pure function that takes in *some state* and an *event* and computes the *next state* as a return value if the machine defines a transition for this combination of input state and event. *It's like a mathematical calculation and
truthful to the [formal definition of a finite state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine#Mathematical_model).*

```js
const nextState = machine.transition('some state', { type: 'SOME_EVENT' })
```

It's the same in XState: the machine's [transition function](https://stately.ai/docs/xstate/running-machines/intro#running-machines-as-pure-functions) is a pure function that computes the next `State` object (see [State API](https://stately.ai/docs/xstate/running-machines/intro#state-api)) **without performing any actions**<sup>[1]</sup> of the machine. While the [old XState docs](https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/transitions.html#machine-transition-method) show some examples using this function, it's rarely used in practice.

Instead, **in most cases you run the machine as a service which also executes its actions**. You can do this with the [interpret](https://stately.ai/docs/xstate/running-machines/intro#interpret) function or helper functions like `useMachine()` from one of the [framework-specific packages](https://stately.ai/docs/category/xstate-packages) and then sending events to the machine with `send()`.

```js
import { createMachine, interpret } from 'xstate';

const machine = createMachine({/* your machine definition */});

const actor = interpret(machine).start();

actor.send({ type: 'WALKING' })
actor.send({ type: 'AT_SAFE_ZONE' })
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> By the way, `createMachine()` runs the entry action of the initial state if an entry action is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Using `const service = interpret(machine)` solved the issue.